# cognos 10.2 filter prompt

Tags: filter, prompt, cognos

I’m using COGNOS 10.2 when i tried to filter my Value prompt (it has been checked or not) it doesn’t work.

for example:
Value prompt 1 has blue, yellow, green
Value prompt 2 has good bad excellent

What I need is to add filter On my page as the following:
if prompt 1 has a value and prompt2 the user did not choose any value(NULL) then in the result (report page) I want to show the query result except prompt 2 choice bad

in my query I have two filters:
[DataItem1]=?prompt1?
[DataItem2]=?prompt2?

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work:

```
(?prompt1? is not missing AND ?prompt2? is missing AND [DataItem1] = ?prompt1? AND [DataItem2] <> 'bad')
OR
(?prompt1? is not missing AND ?prompt2? is not missing AND [DataItem1] = ?prompt1? AND [DataItem2] = ?prompt2?)
```

You may have to add additional tests of ?prompt1? and ?prompt2? depending on if they are required etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear, but I think you'll need to use some sort of if/then logic in your filter.  Something like

```
if (?prompt1? is null) then ([DateItem2] <> bad)
else ([DataItem1] = ?prompt1? and [DataItem2] = ?prompt?)
```